# GitHub Default Reviewers & Mandatory Reviewers

Tags: github

I work on a dev team where we have two levels.

1. General Devs
2. Senior Devs

Our code is stored in a GH repo and we have a GH Team per level (gen-dev, sr-dev) and want to accomplish the following:

1. Both General & Senior Devs are automatically added as reviewers to any PRs
2. Senior Devs must approve the PR (it is optional if general devs do or do not).

We thought this would be easy to setup but we are struggling. It seems we can 'Require Review from Code Owners' which helps with requirement #2 but we cannot figure out how to do #1.

If we add the general devs to Code Owners then requirement #1 is met but #2 no longer is.

Has anyone got something like this to work? Are there approaches folks are using to meet the spirit of our requirements?

Answer (score 0):

After adding the Sr.devs as CODEOWNERS to the repo.

Have you tried to add a branch protection rule to the branch?
Here's an example where you gonna need a review, and only the codeowners are required. Others can review, but are not required.

Also, check [reviewer auto-assignment](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/organizing-members-into-teams/managing-code-review-settings-for-your-team)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the info but this does not quite answer the question. CODEOWNERS only let's me do half of what I want.